# Pandoc markdown bold and color

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, renewcommand

I am using pandoc and write my text in markdown. To create my own style I use a custom latex template.

**I want to style all bold words with a color. So when I type `**a word**` this word should not only be bold, but also e.g. blue.**

Using the following in my latex template file

```
\newcommand\boldblue[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\textbf}{\boldblue}
```

gives me an error when converting to pdf using

`pandoc myfile -f markdown -t latex --template==mytemplate -o myfile.pdf`

which says

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry (grouping levels = 255)

However: when I only set the newcommand

```
\newcommand\boldblue[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}
```

I can write `$\boldblue{some text}$` within my markdown file and it works.

Question: how do I set a new command for `**<word>**`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After some more research I found the following solution using `\let` which works:

```
\let\oldtextbf\textbf
\renewcommand\textbf[1]{{\color{blue}\oldtextbf{#1}}}
```

Using this code in a template file converts markdown's `**<some text>**` to bold and blue in latex / pdf.